# Iterate array of hashes and display in dropdown in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, hashmap, traversal

my array of hash is the below one.

```
[{"status"=>"Submitted", "reachable"=>false}, 
{"status"=>"Replied", "reachable"=>false}, 
{"status"=>"Answered", "reachable"=>false}, 
{"status"=>"Assigned", "reachable"=>false}, 
{"status"=>"Started", "reachable"=>true}, 
{"status"=>"Closed", "reachable"=>false}, 
{"status"=>"Canceled", "reachable"=>true}]
```

I need the "`status`" values and display them in a dropdown in a html with embedded ruby code. Can anyone of you let me know the sample code ? 
I am pretty much new to ruby and getting confused alot in iterations and displaying the values in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as below:

```
array = [{"status"=>"Submitted", "reachable"=>false}, 
        {"status"=>"Replied", "reachable"=>false}, 
        {"status"=>"Answered", "reachable"=>false}, 
        {"status"=>"Assigned", "reachable"=>false}, 
        {"status"=>"Started", "reachable"=>true}, 
        {"status"=>"Closed", "reachable"=>false}, 
        {"status"=>"Canceled", "reachable"=>true}]

p array.map{|h| h["status"] }
# >> ["Submitted", "Replied", "Answered", "Assigned", "Started", "Closed", "Canceled"]
```

Comment: babai. Thanx. but again need some help plz.

"`<option value = '#{p (JSON.parse(disp)).map{|h| h['status_name'] }}'>#{p (JSON.parse(disp)).map{|h| h['status_name'] }}</option>`"

I need the above values in an option list/dropdown. Is the above code correct?

Comment: @user19098 As per your question I gave this solution.. But don't know anything about ROR.. So can't help. But my answer will work 100% if you fit it properly in your code base..

Comment: Yes it works perfectly as you mentioned. I am able to get it as an array of status names. But was trying to get that names in a dropdown list !

Comment: @user19098 Use `puts` instead of `p`.. :)